# rosserial with arduino NO node!

Tags: ros, rosseral-arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have searched the solution for my problem,however i am still puzzled.
below is my problem:
1.I download the examples from the Arduino IDE on my Uno 238P

2.execute :roscore , rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0,

output:

[INFO] [WallTime: 1344165710.415424] [0.000000] ROS Serial Python Node

[INFO] [WallTime: 1344165710.434731] [0.000000] Connected on /dev/ttyACM0 at 57600 baud

But, when i list the topics:
/rosout
/rosout_agg

and service list:
/rosout/get_loggers
/rosout/set_logger_level

i have found that others terminal will show :

[INFO] [WallTime: 1342164886.822488] ROS Serial Python Node

[INFO] [WallTime: 1342164886.825278] Connected on /dev/ttyACM0 at 57600 baud

[INFO] [WallTime: 1342164888.953740] Note: publish buffer size is 512 bytes

[INFO] [WallTime: 1342164888.974499] Starting service client, waiting for service 't

so ,how to solve it ?thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40557/rosserial-with-arduino-no-node!/) by [bobliao](https://answers.ros.org/users/2976/bobliao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it .i don't konow why ,i just restarted my computer~~~it works.
btw:remeber to edit the ttyACM0 in the serial_node.py !!!

---

Originally posted by [bobliao](https://answers.ros.org/users/2976/bobliao/) with karma: 46 on 2012-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0